# Do we have a option to get data in KSQL streams from specific time-period/Timestamp

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-platform

I know , in KSQL we can set offset to earliest or latest But can we get data from specific time period i.e I need to get data inserted to a topic from 06-May-2020 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ksqlDB you can query from the beginning (`SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'earliest';`) or end of a topic (`SET 'auto.offset.reset' = 'latest';`).

You cannot currently (0.8.1 / CP 5.5) seek to an arbitrary offset.

What you *can* do is start from the earliest offset and then use `ROWTIME` in your predicate to identify messages that match your requirement.

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM MY_SOURCE_STREAM 
WHERE  ROWTIME>=1588772149620
```

Note that this scans through sequentially so depending on how much data you have in your topic may not be particularly fast.

Comment: Thanks @Robin Moffatt. I can understand setting earliest and getting data is a performance issue. I can use this solution when KSQL struggles to stream data . Can you please suggest how to add ROWTIME in predicate in KSQL query. Please provide a sample KSQL query if my ROWTIMW is '1588772149620'

Comment: i've added an example

Comment: Can i get messages from ROWTIME=1588772149620 ? I believe this query will fetch only single record . Basically KSQL streams are getting stopped if no data a pushed for couple of days .  So i wan a restart a stream from last message which I consumed .

Comment: I've updated my example to use `greater than or equal to` instead of `equal to` in the predicate

Comment: If you had a consumer then it was restarted, is there any way to get the records that were missed during the restart process?